# CSSing a input type submit only - not for all inputs while i cannot use change the html at all

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change the way a submit button looks - i am unable to us id or class or anything like that.

i have a div - inside this div 2 inputs 1 is a text the other is submit let say the div's class is holder.

```
<div class="holder">
<input type="text" name="somename" value="somevalue">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="save changes">
</div>
```

my current css is:

```
.holder input, textarea {
width:250px;
}
```

However for this change both input types. and i am trying to change them individually.

Comment: Your div says `class="holder"` but you have `#holder` in the CSS. Use `.holder` for classes, `#holder` for IDs.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can specify the specific attributes required for css properties:

```css
.holder input[type=submit] {
  width:250px;
}
```

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors

Basically, it means that the width property only applies to `<input>` tags inside the #holder container IF the type attribute has a value of "submit".

You can also use this on the name attribute:

```css
.holder input[name=submit] {
  width:250px;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The selector for the submit input would be:

```
.holder input[type="submit"]
```

Note that your div has a *class* of "holder", not an id of "holder", so use `.` not `#`.

Comment: @NetaMeta - It works in IE from version 7 onwards, and in all the other major browsers as shown here: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t13 (And obviously you'd use `.holder input[type="text"]` for the text field.)